# Put image inside anchor tag

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am having an issue in Joomla. (I'm using Joomla 1.5)

When I write code like this in Joomla editor:

```
[a tag href="www.something.com"][img src="modules/someimage.jpeg"/][/a]
```

the anchor tag does not come.

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

try this out. let me know if you come across any issues.

```
<a href="www.something.com"><img src="modules/someimage.jpeg" /></a>
```

Comment: I have tried that only...but i dont know how to write tags thats y i wrote like this